# "Кулинария"

Tags: орфоэпия

Слышала, что "КулинАрия" - это приготовление пищи, а "кулинарИя" - магазин, торгующий продуктами питания. Это правда? И почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

КУЛИНАРИЯ - это искусство приготовления пищи, а также сами кушанья (собирательное сущ.)Допустимы оба ударения. Если магазин называется "Кулинария", (как "Продукты", "Колбасы"), то ударение то же.